# Exlude one directory wit 7zip terminal

Tags: command-line, backup, 7zip

I have tried this many times but not yet got it. How to use 7zip to zip directory without one directory inside other. Like:

I have a folder `/home/files/` and inside that, `directory1/` and `directory2/`.

So how to 7zip files without `directory1/`

One example what I had tested:

```
7z a -t7z /home/backups/backup /home/files -x!/directory1
```

Comment: Have a look at this - http://superuser.com/questions/682961/how-to-exclude-a-folder-in-7zip

Comment: @Raphael Tried add flag -mx0 -x!directory1\ but it just says bash: !directory1/: event not found

Answer (score 0):

Use find in conjunction with your command `7z`

```
find /directory/to/zip -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name "ExcludeMe" -exec 7z {} +
```